# How to get the error from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I have a Future Builder, waiting for fetched Data from Firestore.
Now I want to get the error type (`snapshot.hasError`) to show the user, if a network problem occured.

My FutureBuilder:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
          children = <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: color == null
                  ? new Container(
                      child: Html(
                      data: snapshot.data,
                    ))
                  : new Container(
                      child: Html(
                          data: snapshot.data,
                          style: {"html": Style(color: Color(color))}),
                    ),
            ),
          ];
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          children = <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.error_outline,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 60,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text(
                'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ];
        } else {
          children = <Widget>[
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ];
        }
```

Fell free to ask for additional Information.
Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two issues ([1](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/384) and [2](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2334)) reporting this on GitHub that have been merged into a [single issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1223). In a [comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1223#issuecomment-654957863) it is explained that this issue has already been solved and merged into the `master` branch. As per [this comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2582#issuecomment-658152748) it was pre-released on the 14th of July.